# How to update multiple dataframe column cells using function return values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a follow up question from my previous question here [How to update dataframe cells using function return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61647693/how-to-update-dataframe-cells-using-function-return-values/61647721?noredirect=1#comment109046741_61647721)

I have the following dataframe called df1,

```
    country ticker price  exchange dateupdated
0   US      MSFT   105.32 Nasdaq   05-May-2019
1   US      AAPL
2   GERMANY NSU.DE 10.42  XETRA    06-May-2019
3   SG      D05.SI
4   AUS     WOW.AX
```

I have a function called data_get that looks like this. It takes in the ticker, from the ticker column, example 'MSFT' and it returns a list.

```
def data_get(ticker):
   listofdata = somefunction
   return listofdata 

listofdata  = data_get('AAPL')
```

listofdata is a list of strings containing, price, exchange and dateupdated.

```
listofdata = ['150.22', 'Nasdaq', '05-May-2020']
```

The function has to go online to look up the data so it takes a few seconds to run each time.

I want to only use this function on the cells which don't have a price in them, (price cells are empty).

So the function would only be used on rows 1, 3 & 4 in this dataframe and update the price, exchange and dateupdated values in them to look something like this.

```
    country ticker price  exchange dateupdated
0   US      MSFT   105.32 Nasdaq   05-May-2019
1   US      AAPL   150.22 Nasdaq   05-May-2020
2   GERMANY NSU.DE 10.42  XETRA    06-May-2019
3   SG      D05.SI 23.44  SGX      04-May-2020
4   AUS     WOW.AX 12.33  ASX      04-May-2020
```

To summarize, how do I;

1. apply the data_get function to only the rows in which price is empty (1, 3, 4),
2. use the ticker column string (AAPL, D05.SI, WOW.AX) as an input for the data_get function,
3. use the list output from the data_get function and update the price, exchange and dateupdated columns?

It would also be a bonus if I could convert the strings to a float for the price column and a date for the dateupdated column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) where the values are `nan`

```
df.loc[df.prices.isnull(), ['price','exchange','dateupdated']] =
    df.loc[df.prices.isnull(), 'ticker'].apply(data_get)
```

Comment: is there a difference between using isna and isnull?

Comment: `isnull` will identify `NaT`, `None` and `NaN` values.

Comment: for the second part, df[df.prices.isnull(), 'ticker'].apply(data_get), is there a difference between using that and df.loc[df.prices.isnull(), 'ticker'].apply(data_get) ?

Comment: In this context, there is no big difference more than just saving some syntax, however in general terms `loc` allows you to modify the dataframe, and `[]` might be more flexible to quickly select a couple of columns. The intial syntax was incorrect, I have added add edit to keep some consistency.

Answer (score 0):

## Return Type : list directly added to respective columns

I did it this way, keeping in mind you are returning a list, so to modify the update the data points individually,

`df.loc[df.Price].isnull(),['Price','Exchange','Update_date']]  = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df.Price.isnull(),'Ticker'].apply(data_get).to_dict()).transpose().rename(columns={0:'Price',1:'Exchange',2:'Update_date'})`

This single line would directly take the dataframe and based on your function's return type, add the list elements in order to the corresponding columns in the dataframe